# Combinatorial Argument Proof

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Prove: $c(40,5) = c(17,5) + c(17,4) + c(23,1) +...+ c(23,5)$

where c is  the binomial coefficient.

Can I use a combinatorial argument to prove?

Answer (score 5):

I can’t think of any likely expansion of what you’ve written that makes it true. What *is* true is that

$$\begin{align*}\binom{40}5&=\binom{17}5+\binom{17}4\binom{23}1+\binom{17}3\binom{23}2+\\&+\binom{17}2\binom{23}3+\binom{17}1\binom{23}4+\binom{23}5\;,
\end{align*}$$

and it has a very straightforward combinatorial proof.

HINT: You’re trying to count $5$-element subsets of the set $\{1,\ldots,40\}$. Any such subset might have some of its elements from the set $\{1,\ldots,17\}$ and the rest from the set $\{18,19,\ldots,40\}$. If it has $k$ elements from $\{1,\ldots,17\}$, it must have $5-k$ from $\{18,\ldots,40\}$.

- How many elements are there in $\{18,\ldots,40\}$?
- How many ways are there to choose $k$ elements from $\{1,\ldots,17\}$?
- How many ways are there to choose $5-k$ elements from $\{18,\ldots,40\}$?